# Two trigonometric integrals: looking for a transformation

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration

I have two integrals of trigonometric functions and I would like to ask:

> **QUESTION.** Is there a transformation rule (or general principle) to show this equality?
> $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{2\sin^4\theta+2\cos^4\theta}}
> =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{\sin^4\theta+6\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta+\cos^4\theta}}$$

Comment: The denominators are the same but shifted by $\pi/4$: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%282+Sin%5Bx%2BPi%2F4%5D%5E4+%2B+2+Cos%5Bx%2BPi%2F4%5D%5E4%29+-+%28Sin%5Bx%5D%5E4%2B+6+Sin%5Bx%5D%5E2+Cos%5Bx%5D%5E2+%2B+Cos%5Bx%5D%5E4%29

Comment: "transaction"? should be *transformation*?

Comment: Yes, "transformation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking it up from Matt F.'s comment, the substitution
$$\theta=g(\alpha):=
\left(\alpha -\frac{\pi }{4}\right)1\left(\alpha \ge\frac{\pi }{4}\right)+\left(\alpha +\frac{\pi }{4}\right)
   1\left(\alpha < \frac{\pi }{4}\right)$$
in the first integral transforms it to the second one.

The transformation $g\colon[0,\pi/2)\to[0,\pi/2)$ is a bijection preserving the Lebesgue measure.

---

Here is the image of Mathematica notebook confirming/illustrating what was said above:

[image]